# Charles proxy has content unreadable even if SSL proxing has been enabled

Tags: ssl, charles-proxy

I have configured Charles correctly, with SSL proxying enabled even at the Client specific level as per instructions [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/#qa_07363181-1adc-40a1-8719-2ac14781d811) ( by right clicking on the client--> ENABLE SSL PROXING).
However I see still unreadable content like this:
[image: unreadable content]

Not sure what else to do, any help?

Comment: Did you enable the SSL proxying for the domains that you wish to decrypt?

Comment: Hi,yes i did that too. it s done by righ clicking on the domain and Enable SSL proxying. right?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this? `*.*` enabled SSL proxying for all the domains. You can add your required domain instead of the wild card.

[image]

Comment: Hi, i have done that too but content is still unreadable

Comment: i get this once I use a wildcard: You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.

Comment: The root certificate of the Charles needs to be trusted. You can download that certificate from the “Help” section